# How to change the orientation of the iPad simulator?

Tags: ipad, screen-orientation, ios-simulator

How can we change the orientation of the iPad simulator?

For the Android tablet simulators the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> combination is used to change the orientation from portrait to landscape, similarly what is to be used to change the orientation of simulator from "portrait" to "landscape" and back to "portrait"?

Comment: is this for windows? where to get it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd>/<kbd>Arrow Left</kbd>

Comment: Really unintuitive eh; found the answer on SO instead of Apple making it more obvious. :)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>, definitely.

Answer (score 7):

Open the Simulator, click Hardware>Rotate Left or Rotate Right

Answer (score 0):

In my case, shortcuts in Safari were not working instead selecting then click the device will change its orientation.

Answer (score 0):

While all the above mentioned answers work perfectly fine.

I recently wanted to check my app against Face Up/Down orientations. None of the answers above made it possible(unless I am missing something). But the same can be achieved by clicking on **Hardware > Orientation** and then select the orientations you are after.

[image: Change Simulator Orientations]